# Is there any option to create virtual machine in Esxi hypervisor directly using any of the sdks provided by vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

Currently I'm trying to create a vm in a Esxi server using Perl SDK provided by the vmware. The Vcenter host and name must be specified in create_vm.pl to create the vms in the Esxi server directly.
Is there any other SDK(like java) supports to install the vm directly on the Esxi serve without specifying the Vcenter.

link:https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/viperltoolkit/doc/utilityappsdoc/vmcreate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the IP or hostname of the ESX/i host where it asks for vCenter. Keep in mind write operations are only supported on licensed versions of ESX/i so if you are using the free version it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used PERL SDK for VMware, but I have used PowerCLI and PyVmomi for my tasks and the APIs require Host/vCenter IP as their host input.

When you provide VC as the host input, you get the objects related to vCenter for that VM, and if you provide ESXi host IP, you can create,manipulate VMs based on the limits of an ESXi server